# Funções e métodos no PHP são case-insensitive?

Tags: php, classes, funções, sintaxe, case-insensitive

A algum tempo atrás, por um acidente na hora de um *debug* percebi que o PHP não faz diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas na hora do chamamento de uma função.

Exemplo:

```
print_r($teste);

print_R($teste);

Print_R($teste);
```

Também a mesma coisa ocorre para os métodos da classe:

```
    $fileIterator = new FileSystemIterator(__DIR__);

    $fileIterator->current();
    $fileIterator->Current();

    foreach ($fileIterator as $file) {
        echo   $file->getRealPath();
        echo $file->getRealpath();
        echo $file->GETREALPATH();

   }
```

Para descobrir qual é o nome "original" do método `getRealPath`, eu usei o `get_class_methods` em `FileSystemIterator`. E o resultado foi:

```
[32] => getRealPath
```

E no Manual do PHP também está assim.

A pergunta é: mesmo sendo *case-insensitive*, por conta de ter um "nome padrão" definido para os métodos e funções, devo me preocupar em escrevê-los exatamente como eles estão no manual?

Pois, pela minha memória, sei que o `FileSystemIterator` tem um método chamado `getRealPath`, porém às vezes esqueço como se escreve (se é `getRealPath` ou `getRealpath`), e, por funcionar, deixo do jeito que está mesmo.

Eu deveria me preocupar com essa "escrita" na hora do chamamento do método?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

São *case sensitive*:

- Variáveis
- Constantes
- Chaves de *arrays*
- Propriedades de classes
- Constantes de classes

Não são *case sensitive*:

- Funções
- Construtores de classes
- Métodos de classes
- Palavras-chave e construções da linguagem (`if`, `else`, `null`, `foreach`, `echo`, etc.)

Faz sentido esta diferenciação? Pra mim não. Embora possa haver uma explicação técnica para isto, ou tudo deveria ser sensível ou nada deveria.

Os primeiros são chaves de *hashes*, por isto é mais complicado dar a insensibilidade - embora possível (mas trocando a implementação e não usando *hash*). O segundo grupo é feito pelo compilador e é mais fácil resolver a insensibilidade.

No que não é sensível o meu conselho é escrever corretamente mesmo que não seja necessário. Por nenhuma razão específica a não ser escrever de uma forma limpa, correta, praticar fazer o certo sempre. Se não há desvantagens em fazer o certo, então faça.

- [Documentação de variáveis](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).
- [Documentação de funções](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).
- [Documentação de constantes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu pensava em querer escrever da forma correta por outro motivo: "vai que o PHP muda tudo nas versões futuras!"

Comment: É uma preocupação, mas não acho ela válida. Se a linguagem fizer isto vira outra linguagem.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Não cabe mencionar que `TRUE` e `FALSE` são case-insensitive, apesar de serem constantes (são construtos da linguagem, sim; como você observou, a distinção não faz sentido…)?

Answer (score 5):

Funções, assim como métodos de classe, não são case sensitive.

> Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Acredito que esse comportamento se deva exatamente pelo motivo que você expôs (dúvidas em nomes de métodos, funções nativas e funções definidas pelo usuário). Normalmente os nomes funções são compostos por duas ou mais palavras e aí acabam originando essas dúvidas.

Apenas complementando: apesar dos nomes das funções do PHP não seguirem uma norma específica (inclusive essa é uma das principais críticas à linguagem), existem diversas convenções adotadas no PHP (e em outras linguagens):

- Nomes de métodos de classe são `camelCase` com a inicial minúscula;
- Nomes de funções nativas e definidas pelo usuário são `snake_case`.

Tente se lembrar dessas regras, além das peculiaridades de algumas funções do PHP, e você vai acertar quase 100% nos nomes das funções e métodos.