# PDO conexão com banco

Tags: php, pdo

Bom galera, estou começando a estudar sobre PDO, porem logo em minha primeira atividade está ocorrendo um erro, segue abaixo todas as informações.

CODIGO Objeto.php

```
<?php

$cli = new Produtos();
$cli->insert();
```

CODIGO Produto.php

```
<?php

class Produtos extends Conexao{

    public function insert(){

        $this->conectar();

    }
}
```

CODIGO Conexao.php

```
class Conexao{

    private static $conexao;

        public function conectar(){
            try{

                if (!isset(self::$conexao)) {
                    self::$Conexao = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost; dbname = renanmeh_bd_projeto","root","")
                }

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "Erro ao conectar ao banco ".$e->getMessage;
            }
            return self::$conexao
        }
    }
```

Basicamente, este é apenas um teste, onde tenho objeto que instancia a classe produto, e esta classe produto faz uma requisição na classe conexão.

Comment: Qual erro? cadê a mensagem?

Comment: Você informou sua senha no `PDO`, ou só omitiu na sua questão?

Comment: Meu BD não tem senha, ele vem com o root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu código tem uma serie de pequenos erros:

Na linha onde o PDO é instanciado está faltando um ponto e vírgula e variáveis, propriedades etc são case sensitive ou seja maiusculas e minusculas fazem diferença o nome da propriedade definida no ínicio é `$conexao` e não `$Conexao`(como visto na atribuição).

No echo dentro do catch [getMessage()](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php) é um método logo o uso de parêntesses é obrigatório.

No return também falou um ponto e vírgula.

```
class Conexao{
   private static $conexao;
   public function conectar(){
        try{
            if (!isset(self::$conexao)) {
                //Não é $Conexao
                self::$conexao = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=renanmeh_bd_projeto","root",""); //;
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Erro ao conectar ao banco ".$e->getMessage(); //método
        }
        return self::$conexao; //;
    }
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

[funções e métodos no PHP são case-insensitive?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50316/91)

Comment: Ainda continua aparecendo o erro.
Fatal error: Class 'Produtos' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pi\PHPOO com PDO\classes\Objeto.php on line 3

Comment: No arquivo `objeto.php` vc precisa fazer o include das classes. @renan rodrigues

Comment: Isso, eu conseguir aqui, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Renan rodrigues se tive interesse pode pesquisar por autoloading e psr-4, é uma forma de fazer o carregamento da classes ao invés de usar include.