# Como ficaria uma classe PHP para fazer um pesquisa no banco de dados com PDO

Tags: php, pdo, framework, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer o meu `framework`, já consegui criar uma classe chamada `Model`, dentro dela tem uma função chamada `getDataBaseConnection()` e agora como que faço? Não consigo criar uma outra função para pegar informações do `Database`, lembrando que estou fazendo com `PDO`.

Comment: Caso sua pergunta não seja a mesma da indicada, seria legal [edit] e acrescentar as partes específicas do seu problema que não se encontrem no link acima (se for o caso, depois de editar deixe um comentário, que eu releio).

Comment: Aqui tem outro exemplo nas respostas http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67465/pdo-conex%c3%a3o-com-banco e aqui na pesquisa tem mais informações http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pdo

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow, sua pergunta parece um pouco ampla, cite  qual o seu problema específico e parte do código. Quando iniciei em `php` também fiz uma biblioteca para PDO: https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO mas há tempo que não faço commits e ela está com problemas no `WHERE`